# In Rust, what is the lock-free alternative of Arc<RefCell<T>> if T is already Sync & lock-free?

Tags: rust, atomic, smart-pointers

Considering the following example:

```rust
pub trait Fusion: Send + Sync {
...
}


let ff2: Arc<RefCell<(Box<dyn Fusion>, bool)>> = ...;
```

all Impls of Fusion already has atomic, lock-free algorithm built-in, they are safe to be shared in multiple threads. It should be noted that both RwLock and Mutex cannot be used here as they are too inefficient.

However, ff2 (mutable reference counting) cannot be used in another thread, the compiler will complain:

```
error[E0277]: `RefCell<(Box<dyn Fusion>, bool)>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:188:36
    |
188 |           let handle = thread::spawn(move || loop {
    |  ______________________-------------_^
    | |                      ...
196 | |         });
    | |_________^ `RefCell<(Box<dyn Fusion>, bool)>` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

I need to find an alternative smart pointer that supports both reference counting and lock-free mutability. To my knowledge, this feature doesn't exist in vanilla Rust. What should be done in this case?

Comment: If `Fusion` has an "atomic, lock-free algorithm" then this implies that it already has interior mutability, e.g. all methods of `Fusion` should take `&self` instead of `&mut self`, which would mean you can simply remove the `RefCell` layer. (If it receives `&mut self` then it wouldn't need any kind of atomics or lock-free sharing, because you'd already have exclusive access.) If this is not the case then you need to explain what this "atomic, lock-free algorithm" does and why the methods of `Fusion` can't receive `&self`.

Comment: here's a quick implementation of @cdhowie's comment for a visual:
```
pub trait Fusion: Send + Sync {
    // all methods take &self
}


struct exampleFusion;
impl Fusion for exampleFusion{
    // ...
}

let some_fusion = exampleFusion;
let ff2: Arc<(Box<dyn Fusion>, bool)> = Arc::new((Box::new(some_fusion), true));```

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps you need write access to the `bool`. In that case you can just use `Arc<(Box<dyn Fusion>, AtomicBool)>` but better would be putting them together into a proper struct. This could also allow you to avoid the box if you provide a function to obtain a `&dyn Fusion` from the value in the `Arc`.